# Using `window.jQuery` instead of yarn version

Tags: javascript, jquery, node-modules, vite

I'm trying to covert to Vite 3 with Vite Ruby (on Rails) from Webpacker & Webpack. One of the main blockers I've noticed is that my system is a CMS. Some of our older customers have some jQuery code directly within `<script>` tags in `<head>`. I can't easily change this, and because importing jQuery within Vite and assigning it to `window` with something like:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery
```

happens in a deferred manner with `type="module"` jquery isn't initialised when the code in the `<head>` runs. I've resorted to loading jQuery via a CDN `<script>` tag so that it's loaded synchronously before the `<head>` code executes. No big deal.

The problem I've encountered from here is when trying to use the `jstree` jQuery plugin. This is able to be imported, but it seems to automatically load the `node_modules` jQuery dependency, then mount itself on to that. When then subsequently trying to find `$(element).jstree`, we're referring to the `window` copy of jQuery and jstree doesn't exist on that. I can fix this by `import $ from 'jquery'` just before importing jstree, but then I'm essentially getting the user to download jQuery twice.

What I'd like to do is have the `window` version of jQuery provided any time a package tries to import `'jQuery'`. I've tried rollup's `external` configuration but that didn't seem to work. Keen to give anything a go really. For now I've resorted to loading jstree from a CDN too but that feels less clean.

I've tried the following config so far:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import RubyPlugin from 'vite-plugin-ruby'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    RubyPlugin(),
  ],
  server: {
    hmr: {
      host: 'vitedevserver.test',
      clientPort: 443
    }
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['jquery'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          jquery: '$'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's quite a bit that I needed to understand about this issue first.

Vite uses `esbuild` for "Dependency Pre-Bundling" in development. So it's `esbuild` that changes require('jquery') into a full code injection of the jQuery library within the file that included it. We need to use a plugin at the `esbuild` level to override this behaviour in the case of jQuery and just point to the copy of `jQuery` that already exists on `window`. Here's my final config. I needed to install the following plugin too:

```
$ yarn add @fal-works/esbuild-plugin-global-externals
```

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import RubyPlugin from 'vite-plugin-ruby'
import { globalExternals } from "@fal-works/esbuild-plugin-global-externals";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    RubyPlugin()
  ],
  server: {
    hmr: {
      host: 'vitedevserver.test',
      clientPort: 443
    }
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      plugins: [globalExternals({ jquery: { type: "cjs", varName: "$" } })]
    }
  }
})
```

It's important to target `cjs` or the global still didn't work in the case of `jstree`.

Whether this will be a problem in the production build that uses `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` remains to be seen. I assume I might need to use a plugin in that environment for this too.